# Rails 4, Adding custom layout, got error message

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Added two layout in layout folder

layouts/application.html.erb
layouts/location.html.erb

location.html for Location controller

My stylesheets

stylesheets/application.css
stylesheets/locations.css

**application.css**

application.css

```
*= require tree
*= require normalize
*= require foundation.min
*= require select2
*/
```

**location.css**

```
*= require tree
*= require normalize
*= require sortable_tree
*= require nested_options
*= require foundation.min
*/
```

layouts/application.html.erb

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

layouts/location.html.erb

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'location', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

> i've also added javascript_include_tag same added application.js and
>   location.js

got error message **Asset filtered out and will not be served**

Comment: Can you give us more information on the error? Is it a JS or HTML error?

Comment: Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( customlocation.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server

Comment: i added Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( customlocation.css ), not working

Comment: Did you actually add `%w( customlocation.css )`? Since your stylesheet is called `location`, you should add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( location.css )`

Comment: Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( location.css ) added

Comment: but not work, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add both your files to `precompile`, not just `location.css` but also `location.js`:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( location.css location.js )
```